# Cannot execute a stored procedure from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, phpmyadmin, privileges

I'm trying to create stored procedures for my teammates who are non-technical and can't write MySQL queries on their own.

They are currently accessing the database through phpMyAdmin.

However, when I create stored procedures, my teammates are unable to execute them from phpMyAdmin. They see the procedures, but the "execute" command is absent and everything else is grayed out. Here's an example with a stored procedure named get_transaction_history:

[image]

To be sure, I gave my teammates the permission to execute the stored procedure with the following command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE database.get_transaction_history TO 'teammate1'@'localhost';
```

And indeed, it's possible for them to execute the stored procedure through the CALL command. However, phpMyAdmin won't allow them to execute the stored procedure from its GUI. Yet, it claims that my teammates do have the EXECUTE option granted to them.

[image]

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for those users within phpMyAdmin? I believe they are separate to the permissions on the DB itself.

You can find this on the phpMyAdmin homepage under Privileges.

Answer (score 0):

There are separate user privileges within phpMyAdmin to the DB itself.

Go to the phpMyAdmin homepage and click Privileges and check that the users have the privileges required to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: I have checked and they do.

Comment: Can you show which privileges are assigned to one of the users in question? The DB level Routines privilege is required to execute a stored procedure.

Comment: I've added an image in my initial post.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot test at present. It could be possible that the user requires privileges in phpMyAdmin to perform the actions that the stored procedure itself performs on top of the privilege to execute the routine. Perhaps you could do a simple test of this by creating a routine/stored procedure that does a `select *` and trying to execute it from a user that doesn't have select privileges but has the routine privileges!?

Comment: There are no separate privileges in phpmyadmin as far as I know. This is only a bug

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably facing this bug https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14430

It was fixed in phpmyadmin version 5.10

Solution: check your version and upgrade.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this issue and doing some tests. Thanks.